# How to get table and Bootstrap Buttons to resize based on screen size?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am coding a table that has 2 Bootstrap buttons. The table is inside a `div`.

The table obeys the screen width when the text in the button is short. please check the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot from mobile view - button with short phrase]

However, when I added another button with longer text, the whole table was pushed out as per the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot from mobile view - button with long phrase]

I added `max-width: inherit;` to the table, it didn't work

I also added `word-wrap: break-word;` and `overflow-wrap: break-word;` to the text in the button, but none worked.

I read that these 2 CSS properties work on long text (i.e. if you have one long word like thisisaverylongword), not on long phrases. That's why it is not working on the long phrase.

I will paste my code here, but it will not be meaningful as a script snippet due to plugin-related shortcodes in it.

My question is: How to get the phrase in the bootstrap button to obey the screen width and wrap to several lines?

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #007bff;">
      <th scope="col" style="color: white;">[wpml-string name="Download Button Table Header"]رابط التحميل[/wpml-string]</th>
      <th scope="col" style="color: white;">[wpml-string name="Download Size Table Header"]حجم الملف[/wpml-string]</th>
<th scope="col" style="color: white;">[wpml-string name="Download Count Table Header"]مرات التحميل[/wpml-string]</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: white;">
      <td scope="col"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
        <div class="download-button" onclick="$('.loading').show();">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true" style="color: black;"></span> <a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=[types field='download-link-id'][/types]&type=.pdf&export=download" rel="noopener" style="color: black; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold; word-wrap: break-word;">[wpml-string name="Download Button - Direct"]أضغط للتحميل المباشر[/wpml-string]</a>
        </div></button>
<div class="separator-3"></div>    
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
        <div class="download-button" onclick="$('.loading').show();">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true" style="color: black; word-wrap: break-word;"></span> <a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=[types field='download-link-id'][/types]" rel="noopener" style="color: black; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold;">[wpml-string name="Download Button - Gdrive"]إضغط للتحميل من جوجل درايف[/wpml-string]</a>
        </div></button>

      </td>
      <td scope="col">[types field='download-file-size'][/types]MB</td>
      <td scope="col">[download_count]</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT:** I removed the plugin-related shortcode and created a working script that can be run properly:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #007bff;">
      <th scope="col" style="color: white;">رابط التحميل</th>
      <th scope="col" style="color: white;">حجم الملف</th>
<th scope="col" style="color: white;">مرات التحميل</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: white;">
      <td scope="col"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
        <div class="download-button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true" style="color: black;"></span> <a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=xxx&type=.pdf&export=download" rel="noopener" style="color: black; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold; word-wrap: break-word;">أضغط للتحميل المباشر</a>
        </div></button>
<div class="separator-3"></div>    
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
        <div class="download-button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true" style="color: black; word-wrap: break-word;"></span> <a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=xxx" rel="noopener" style="color: black; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold;">إضغط للتحميل من جوجل درايف</a>
        </div></button>

      </td>
      <td scope="col">MB</td>
      <td scope="col"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think bootstrap have implemented this functionality. but you can update this property with [Responsive breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints).

Comment: @EugineJoseph, I am not saying that bootstrap is the cause or not. I am just explaining my situation in details. My problem is not that the table is not responsive. my problem is that the text doesn't obey the responsiveness and pushes everything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's .btn class has `white-space: nowrap;` by default:

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: $btn-font-weight;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  ...
```

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_buttons.scss#L11

In your theme or styles set it to:

```
.btn {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. it worked perfectly fine. is there a reason for their default settings? I mean: do i need to keep it for bootstrap to function properly?

Comment: Default is just to avoid unexpected wrapping for shorter strings like "Buy Now", etc.  But it's fine to override if you need to in your case.